# Trouble making more than one or two cells into UITableView with different sizes Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to build two (or more) custom cells into table View and without custom classes for each one, I'm using storyboard to cell prototyping and  `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCellName", for: indexPath)` to create different cell from `cellForRowAt` method.

I need cell type 1 with different height than cell type 2 but if a try to use `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` the cell type 2 is not displayed correctly.

I try to build a "dummy project" to understand the right way, here my code:

```
var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

let value = dataArray[indexPath.row]

if (value == "second") || (value == "Hawaii") {
    cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTwo", for: indexPath)
}
let lbl = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel
lbl.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
return cell
```

In ViewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Cells view example]

Every cell with the same size, is not working for me.

Comment: Custom cells = custom classes. There are plenty of tutorials that show how simple it is.

Comment: Why do you first dequeue a cell before checking `value`? Use an `else` to dequeue the proper cell type.

Comment: Also they are all the same size because the content in all of them appears to be the same size. Change the font to be really big in some of the cells or multi line amount of text and you will know if it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a custom cell appearance, you will have to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` - there are some [great tutorials on how to do that](https://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/uitableview).

You then have to register your custom cell, so that your `UITableView` knows about it. See [`register(_:​for​Cell​Reuse​Identifier:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register) method.

In your [`table​View(_:​height​For​Row​At:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview) you can do write the following code in order to figure out the height of particular cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat

     let value = dataArray[indexPath.row]

     if (value == "second") || (value == "Hawaii") {
         return 180.0
     } else {
         return 40.0
     }
}
```